# Python 3 - IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

I'm currently creating a programming language in Python 3.6 and for some reason, the following code produces an `IndexError: string index out of range`.

When I try to execute the following code in a Windows Batch File:

```
@echo off
python run-file.py test.ros
pause
```

But I'm getting the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run-file.py", line 16, in <module>
    if not(value[1][0] == "!") and ignoreline == False:
IndexError: string index out of range
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The `run-file.py` file looks like this:

```
from sys import argv as args
from sys import exit as quit
import syntax

try:
    args[1]
except IndexError:
    print("ERROR: No ROS Code file provided in execution arguments")
    print("Ensure the execution code looks something like this: python run-file.py test.ros")

with open(args[1]) as f:
    ignoreline = False
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    for value in enumerate(content):
        if not(value[1][0] == "!") and ignoreline == False:
            firstpart = value[1].split(".")[0]
            lenoffirstpart = len(value[1].split(".")[0])
            afterpart = str(value[1][lenoffirstpart + 1:])
            apwithcomma = afterpart.replace(".", "', '")
            preprint = str(firstpart + "(" + apwithcomma + ")")
            printtext = preprint.replace("(", "('")
            lastprinttext = printtext.replace(")", "')")
            try:
                exec(str("syntax." + lastprinttext))
            except Exception as e:
                template = "ERROR: An error of type {0} occured while running line {1} because {2}"
                message = template.format(
                    type(e).__name__, str(value[0] + 1), str(e.args[0]))
                print(message)
                quit(1)
        elif content[value[0]][0] == "!!!":
            ignoreline = not(ignoreline)

quit(0)
```

The `syntax.py` file looks like this:

```
def print_message(contents=''):
    print(contents)
```

The `test.ros` file looks like this:

```
! This is a single line comment

!!!
This line should be ignored
and this one as well
!!!

print_message.Hello World
```

The problem appears to be in line 16 of the `run-file.py` file:

```
if not(value[1][0] == "!") and ignoreline == False:
```

I've already tried replacing `value[1][0]` with `(value[1])[0]` and other combinations with brackets to no avail.

It seems like when I try to print the value it behaves as expected and gives me `!` which is the first character of the `test.ros` file but for some reason, it throws an exception when it's in the `if` statement.

If you want any more of the source, it's on Github and you can find the exact commit containing all the files [here](https://github.com/Richienb/ROS-Code/tree/ba7e787eea0ca880efc34d5e5942db9084de2333)

**Update/Solution**

Big thanks to [Idanmel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5042412/idanmel) and [Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) for helping me resolve my issue. You can view the changes I've made [here](https://github.com/Richienb/ROS-Code/commit/b32effc361e6c0008822552e853bab0613c4d5c4)

Comment: You should unpack the return tuple of `enumerate` right away: `for index, value in enumerate(content):`. Then check if the value begins with `!` like `value.startswith('!')`. This will prevent index errors on empty values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've incorporated your suggestion and the one by Idanmel and now it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the 2nd line in test.ros is empty.

You create content in this example to be:

```
['! This is a single line comment',
 '',
 '!!!',
 'This line should be ignored',
 'and this one as well',
 '!!!',
 '',
 'print_message.Hello World']
```

When you try to access content[1][0], you get an IndexError because it's an empty string.

Try removing the empty lines from content by adding an if to the list comprehenssion:

```
content = [x.strip() for x in content if x.strip()]
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added the line of code to the corresponding location.

Comment: Yes! It did work. I've posted an answer outlining my changes.

Comment: @RichieBendall do not post code that you fixed. If you found an answer helpfull, accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ok, I've accepted your post as an answer. Thanks for pointing that out!